# HOw to deny a particular mac address client not to obtain ip/name from dhcp & dns server

Tags: linux

I configures DHCP server on my rhel 5.4 machine.Clients are getting ip from this DHCP server.NO problem upto this..

NOw i want that a particular mac address client do not pick ip from this dhcp server..

Same question is with my DNS server. I want that a particular mac address client do not pick name from this dns server..

PLz discuss in little bit details i am very new in this field.I am learning these things.I hope YOu will give detailed explaiantion..

Thanks IN ADvance friends..

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this quite easily - but by giving them an invalid IP address, not by denying it one. All you have to do is create a second DHCP scope with non-routable IP/NM/DG settings and give the specific MAC address it via a reservation. You can also include non-existant DNS servers in the same DHCP response. If you want to actually stop the traffic from hitting the DHCP/DNS servers then I'd suggest firewalling via IPSec or IP Tables.

Comment: Perhaps one should also note that this will not be a security boundary in any way, if it could be mistaken as such.

Comment: Sir i dont get it what u said plz tell me in simple language so that i can grab..Ok tell me one thing...is it possible that a particular mac address client does not get ip from dhcp server.????? one more thing what will happen if a new client get connected in network but the range of ip which i give in dhcpd.conf file now overflowed(50 range and 50 clients have gotten ip now what is for 51th client)